# Could not archive project in Xcode

Tags: swift, build, nsuserdefaults, archive, ios-app-group

I have iOS application build in `UIKit` with `SwiftUI` widget extension. Until now the archiving worked just fine. I've added App Group to share user defaults in following format: `"group.MYTEAMID.sk.MYNAME.names"`. When I try to archive this project and send it to the App Store Connect I am getting following error:

```
...WidgetExtension:
error build: Command SetOwnerAndGroup failed with a nonzero exit code
```

When I build app locally or on simulator, there is no error at all. Any thoughts? Also, in console I have this log:

```
[User Defaults] Couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x281b7e480> (Domain: group.MYTEAM.sk.MYNAME.names, User: kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost: Yes, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: Yes): Using kCFPreferencesAnyUser with a container is only allowed for System Containers, detaching from cfprefsd
```

Comment: share user defaults from main app to widget is not working in ios16... 
I have just tested it in my application you should have to use coredata

Comment: Hmm, the app with widget is working as expected, just the process of archivation is always failing.

Comment: archive with arm64?

Comment: Yes, as always. Build before went without issues.

Answer (score 2):

After restarting the Xcode and Mac, everything started to working. No mentioned errors, app is successfully archived. Well, the magic happens!